# Delete row if not found within a range

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have tried many variations of code and this has got me the closest.I have 2 worksheets; worksheet1 has total data, worksheet2 has a range which identifys the rows in sheet1 need to be retained, so any value not found in that range should be deleted. When I run the code what was deleted didn't match up, and in a small test it didn't delete any values. What I am I doing wrong?

```
Sub Delete()
    Dim nRng As Range, rng As Range
    Set nRng = Range("Dog") 'Substitute actual name of range
    Set rng = Range("A1", ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)) 
    For Each c In rng 'Look at each item in col K
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(nRng, c.Value) = 0 Then 'Evaluate against named range
        c.EntireRow.Delete 'Delete rows with no match to named range
    End If
    Next   
End Sub
```

Comment: Right off the top, you might be having issues with your `Range` declarations because they are not explicit. You're dealing with two worksheets, so a better assignment for `nRng` would be `Set nRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Worksheet2").Range("Dog")` with a similar, explicit assignment for `rng`

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate the `Range Object` or any Object in a collection backwards if you are deleting them.
The reason is if you delete the instance of that object, VBA retains or remembers its position (does not update upon deletion) and thus skip the actual next object.

**Illustration:**

[image]

So in above illustration, `C4` already took the position of `C3` since it is already deleted.
But `VBA` will continue to check on position 4 since it already pass position 3.
To correctly iterate and delete through your `Range`, do it like this:

```
For i = Rng.Count To 1 Step -1
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(nRng, Rng(i)) = 0 Then
        Rng(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
```

The result would be:

[image]

**Edit1:** Code refactoring suggestions or workarounds

1. If you're using a named Range, be explicit about it.

   ```
   Dim nRng As Range, rng As Range, i As Long
   Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
   Set nRng = ThisWorkbook.Names("mylist").RefersToRange ' mylist is a named range

   With ws ' explicit referencing objects
       Set rng = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
   End With

   ' use of expression.Rows.Count and Range.Range to handle any range size
   For i = rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
       If IsError(Application.Match(rng.Range("A" & _
       i).Value, nRng, 0)) Then rng.Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Delete
   Next
   ```
2. Or a much better way is to get all the values for deletion first and delete in one go. This eliminates the problems with the direction of iteration (forward or backward) stated above.

   ```
   Dim nRng As Range, rng As Range, c As Range
   Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
   Set nRng = ThisWorkbook.Names("mylist").RefersToRange

   With ws
       Set rng = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
   End With

   Dim rngToDelete As Range
   For Each c In rng
       If IsError(Application.Match(c.Value, _
       nRng, 0)) Then
           ' collect all the ranges for deletion first
           If rngToDelete Is Nothing Then
               Set rngToDelete = c
           Else
               Set rngToDelete = Union(rngToDelete, c)
           End If
       End If
   Next
   ' delete in one go
   If Not rngToDelete Is Nothing Then rngToDelete.EntireRow.Delete xlUp
   ```

The second approach for me is the best solution. I personally use that approach in all my codes that requires deletion of ranges. If nothing above works for you, might as well post a sample data we can work on to simulate your issue.

Comment: Excellent answer. Rule of thumb is work backwards when deleting rows. Alternatively, decrement your looping variable accordingly (but be careful not to get stuck in an infinite loop).

Comment: Brilliant, you've really helped me.

Comment: Was fine in test but I ran it on a copy of the actual worksheet and it didn't stop running, deleting all values. Any suggestions?

Comment: @ThomasSharp Ok. As long as you select one(1) column range and iterate through it, it will be fine. But not two(2) or more columns. Else, it needs to be adjusted. Also, try replacing your `If Block`. I'll post a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the following code worked on multiple tests

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    'Deletes rows where one cell does not meet criteria
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim i As Long
    lr = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For i = lr To 1 Step -1
            If Application.CountIf(ws2.Range("A:A"), ws1.Cells(i, 1).Value) = 0 Then
                ws1.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```